# UI-Router nested states without nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI-Router and need to have a single parent state that several other states can inherit the results of a resolve from. I have tried every solution found here on SO for this but NOTHING is working. My states look like this:

```
.state('transaction', {
    abstract:true,
    url: '/register/pos/:screen/:document_sid',
    template:'<div ui-view></div>',
    resolve: {
        Document: //the thing I need to have all the children access
    }
})
.state('transaction.view', {
    url:'',
    views:{
        '':{
            templateUrl: '/views/docs/pos-transaction-outer-partial.htm',
            controller:'posdocumentController'
        }
    }
})
.state('transaction.edit', {
    url: '/:mode',
    views:{
        '':{
            templateUrl: '/views/docs/pos-transaction-outer-partial.htm',
            controller:'posdocumentController'
        }
    }
})
.state('transaction.returns', {
    url: '/returns',
    views:{
        '':{
            templateUrl: '/views/pos-itemreturn-partial.htm',
            controller: 'posItemReturnsController'
        }
    }
})
```

When I use `$state.go('transaction.edit')` it works perfectly. Inside the 'posdocumentController' I have a function that calls `$state.go('transaction.returns')` and I can see the route change and the partial is requested, but the view never changes. According to the docs for [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) the specified views should load in the parents ui-view that is contained within the template. Obviously, for me this is not happening and for the life of me I have not been able to figure out why. I've tried this both with and without the views option and get the same results. Can someone explain why and how I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In details is hidden... in very small detail, in this case.

#### I. Why not working?

Here is a [plunker with **broken**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhLiim7CJsnUtbL3VNPx?p=preview) navigation *(exactly as described in the question above)*

These would be the calls to the above states:

```
ui-sref
transaction.view ({ screen: 1 ,document_sid:2 ,mode:5 })
transaction.edit ({ screen: 1 ,document_sid:2 ,mode:5 })
transaction.returns ({ screen: 1 ,document_sid:2 ,mode:5 })

href
#/register/pos/1/2
#/register/pos/1/2/5
#/register/pos/1/2/returns
```

so, while these could seem as proper state calls, the last two, edit and returns, could be observed as:

```
// edit link result
params
{
  "screen": "1",
  "document_sid": "2",
  "mode": 5
}
state
{
  "url": "/:mode",
  ...

// returns link result
params
{
  "screen": "1",
  "document_sid": "2",
  "mode": "returns"
}
state
{
  "url": "/:mode",
```

Now it should be clear. The third link (to state `returns`) is in fact navigating to `edit` **again**. Why? because of this states definition:

```
.state('transaction.edit', {
    url: '/:mode',     // here we say :mode is param
    ...
.state('transaction.returns', {
    url: '/returns',   // and 'returns' here is already mapped... above as :mode
```

Check the [**not** working solution here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhLiim7CJsnUtbL3VNPx?p=preview)

#### II. How to make it working

There is a link to [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mz6ngG17GWBkLAkS2gS9?p=preview). The change made is:

> firstly define `returns` and then `edit` state

```
.state('transaction.returns', {
    url: '/returns',   // 'returns' would be evaulated first, and used
    ...
.state('transaction.edit', {
    url: '/:mode',     // only other then returns values will be used here
```

Working solution is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mz6ngG17GWBkLAkS2gS9?p=preview)

Other solution, maybe better, would be to use some regex... to narrow :mode values: [Regex Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters)

> - `'/user/{id:[^/]*}'` - Same as `'/user/{id}'` from the previous example.
> - `'/user/{id:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}}'` - Similar to the previous example, but only matches if the id parameter consists of 1 to 8 hex digits.
> - `'/files/{path:.*}'` - Matches any URL starting with `'/files/'` and captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.
> - `'/files/*path'` - Ditto. Special syntax for catch all.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work in my application. It appears that UI-Router is doing pattern matching on all of the route URLs and basing the result on a non-greedy match. Not sure how I'm going to proceed from here. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, the best you can do, is to check my plunkers. They really show your example, I'd say. The error is there, and the fix as well. Or? I am trying to say, do not give up here. Becuase we know (well I would say) what is the cause of your issue. And there is a way how to fix it. The state definition is dependent on the order... if the url is not clearly distinguished, e.g. '/mode/:mode'

Comment: I've looked at the plunkers. When I transfer that style into my application (which has several more routes) I do not get the same results.

Comment: In case you want me to take a look on your stuff, update plunker or question with other details. Otherwise sorry and good luck...

Comment: Thank you very much for trying. I do appreciate the effort. If it had worked it would have made my day.